# What is the difference between Unicode code points and Unicode scalars?

Tags: unicode, terminology

I see the two being used (seemingly) interchangeably in many cases - are they the same or different? This also seems to depend on whether the language is talking about UTF-8 (e.g. Rust) or UTF-16 (e.g. Java/Haskell). Is the code point/scalar distinction somehow dependent on the encoding scheme?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First let's look at [definitions D9, D10 and D10a, Section 3.4, Characters and Encoding](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G2212):

> D9 **Unicode codespace**:
> A range of integers from 0 to 10FFFF<sub>16</sub>.
>
> D10 **Code point**:
> Any value in the Unicode codespace.
>
> •   A code point is also known as a
> code position.
>
> ...
>
> D10a **Code point type**:
> Any of the **seven fundamental classes** of code points in the standard:
> Graphic, Format, Control, Private-Use, **Surrogate**, Noncharacter, Reserved.
>
> [emphasis added]

Okay, so code points are integers in a certain range. They are divided into categories called "code point types".

Now let's look at [definition D76, Section 3.9, Unicode Encoding Forms](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404):

> D76 **Unicode scalar value**:
> Any Unicode code point except high-surrogate and low-surrogate code points.
>
> • As a result of this definition, the set of Unicode scalar values consists  of the ranges 0 to D7FF<sub>16</sub> and E000<sub>16</sub>
> to 10FFFF<sub>16</sub>, inclusive.

Surrogates are defined and explained in Section 3.8, just before D76. The gist is that surrogates are divided into two categories high-surrogates and low-surrogates. These are used only by UTF-16 so that it can represent all scalar values. (There are 1,112,064 scalars but 2<sup>16</sup> = 65536 is much less than that.)
UTF-8 doesn't have this problem; it is a variable length encoding scheme (code points can be 1-4 bytes long), so it can accommodate encode all scalars without using surrogates.

**Summary:** a code point is either a scalar or a surrogate. A code point is merely a number in the most abstract sense; how that number is encoded into binary form is a separate issue. UTF-16 uses surrogate pairs because it can't directly represent all possible scalars. UTF-8 doesn't use surrogate pairs.

In the future, you might find consulting the [Unicode glossary](https://www.unicode.org/glossary/) helpful. It contains many of the frequently used definitions, as well as links to the definitions in the Unicode specification.

Comment: UTF-8 encodings can be 1-4 bytes long and represent code points of maximum 7-, 11-, 16-, or 21- bits, respectively.  Otherwise, good question and self-answer :^)

Comment: Oops, good catch! I mentally translated 1-4 (8-bit) bytes into bits directly. Of course, that is incorrect.

Comment: "These are used only by UTF-16 so that it can represent all code points" - going by the definitions, I think this should be "so that it can represent all Unicode scalars", as it can't represent the codepoints corresponding to the surrogates themselves.