# How to represent this utf-8 encoded string in Rust?

Tags: rust, utf-8, utf

On this RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7616#page-19 at page 19, there's this example of a text encoded in UTF-8:

```
  J  U+00E4 s  U+00F8 n      D  o  e
  4A C3A4   73 C3B8   6E 20 44  6F 65
```

How do I represent it in a Rust String?

I tried https://mothereff.in/utf-8 and doing `J\00E4s\00F8nDoe` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"Jäsøn Doe"` should work fine. [Rust source files are always UTF-8 encoded](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/input-format.html) and a string literal may contain any Unicode scalar value (that is, [any code point except surrogates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48465265/3650362), which must not be encoded in UTF-8).

If your editor does not support UTF-8 encoding, but supports ASCII, you can use Unicode code point escapes, which are documented in [the Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/tokens.html#character-escapes):

> A *24-bit code point escape* starts with `U+0075` (`u`) and is followed by up to six *hex digits* surrounded by braces `U+007B` (`{`) and `U+007D` (`}`). It denotes the Unicode code point equal to the provided hex value.

suggesting the correct syntax should be `"J\u{E4}s\u{F8}n Doe"`.

Answer (score 4):

You can refer to Rust By Example as everything is not covered in rust eBook

(https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/std/str.html#literals-and-escapes)

You can use the syntax \u{your_unicode}

```rust
let unicode_str = String::from("J\u{00E4}s\u{00F8}nDoe");
println!("{}", unicode_str);
```